# How does contents of the pages load one after another?

Tags: user-interface

In facebook pages content loads one after another.When i scroll down it loads another page.Which technology makes it possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A bit more technical details how that can be done:

- JavaScript function triggered by scroll event of the page
- Function checks if page is scrolled "enough" to load more contents (if you are close to the bottom)
- When necessary, asynchronous call is sent on the background to the server to fetch more contents (AJAX).
- Once content is loaded, it's appended to the bottom of the page (or element of the page)

Comment: Thanks for the answer, it is really simplified and understandable.

Answer (score 0):

It's called infinite scrolling